# A Realm app crashes if in the simulator, and while OSX Realm browser is open.

Tags: ios, realm

Version 0.92.4 of Realm is now available: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v0.92.4/CHANGELOG.md

For some odd reason when I am using an older version of Realm it stops processing my code? is this how realm behaves by default ?

I was using version 0.92.3 then all of a sudden my code stops working.

```
if (!self.inWriteTransaction) {
        try {
            // if the upgrade to write will move the transaction forward,
            // announce the change after promoting
            bool announce = _sharedGroup->has_changed();

            // begin the read transaction if needed
            [self getOrCreateGroup];

            LangBindHelper::promote_to_write(*_sharedGroup); // where the app freezes or halts.
```

So the notification is given there

2015-05-25 14:11:27.346 MoneyFit[25056:251423] Version 0.92.4 of Realm is now available: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v0.92.4/CHANGELOG.md

Edit it turns out you cannot read the default.realm on OSX
and write to the default.realm.

It causes the simulator to crash.

Comment: It shouldn't do. The update checker is completely separate from the rest of the code, and ONLY ever runs in the iOS Simulator; never on a device. What do you mean by your code suddenly stopping to work? What happens?

Comment: I am using the simulator, and running the code in appdelegate.
AppDelegate
 /** Breaking code... **/
    RLMRealm* db = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [db beginWriteTransaction];
    
    [db commitWriteTransaction];

It stops running the code and jumps from db beginwrite to finish the function? let me set a debug point and check

Comment: Hrmm, does it behave the same way on a proper device? How is it breaking exactly? Is an error occurring, or is the app simply hanging?

Comment: The app is hanging let me try a device right now =)

Comment: Okay I am unable to test on a device, I don't have any laying around the office, but it halts the app around LangBindHelper

Comment: Oh dear. This isn't sounding good. That would seem to imply that something's interfering with the write transaction, and it might be 'waiting' for something else to finish up. Do you have any other Realm code in the app delegate before this breaking section? Also, this might be a long shot, but have you tried deleting your app from the Simulator and re-building it again?

Comment: So this is the thread on it It works now https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1993
He switched off the notification (or actually made it recognize that 0.92.3 is the most stable version) so my code now runs again. I think the what ever is performing the notification is blocking the write thread or write transaction